# npm packages added after uninstall dependencies

Tags: npm

Why after calling `npm uninstall` I see message `added packages`?

For example:

```
$ npm uninstall -S redux-devtools-dock-monitor redux-devtools-log-monitor redux-devtools
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

added 115 packages and removed 22 packages in 20.589s
```

For that specific example at least here is some removed packages. Sometimes it just shows only `added <n> packages` message.

Could someone clarify it?

**UPD**: I did a little test from scratch but everything works as I expected when uninstall something. But I see such messages like above in question really often.

Comment: But is it really installing new packages?

Comment: @IsidroTorregrosa good question :) I didn't check. But maybe will do it later. I suggest that maybe it's a result of some tree-shaking... Or not.